# UIViewController Containment Basics - how to display a full screen ViewController over two side-by-side ViewControllers

Tags: ipad, ios5, uiviewcontroller

I have a similar question out there about VC containment that addresses my desired end result, but am asking this hypothetical question to nail down the basic concepts of containment.

I have a main controller container (A) that contains viewController B and viewController C. ViewController B takes up one half of the screen, and C takes up the other half.

When I press a button on VC B, I want another view controller (D) to take up the entire screen.

I have the code to display the "split" controllers B and C, but need to know how to get viewController D to display.

My question: What code would get viewController D to display, and where would it be called from?

I have spent a couple hours looking for a question involving this pattern, to no avail. I'm assuming that VC A would be in charge displaying it (otherwise it couldn't fill the entire screen), and the button on VC B would involve VC A using parentViewController - but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reusability reasons, view controller B and C (and D) should act independently of the container view controller. This way, they can be used inside and outside of a container view controller.

What you want would be possible using a delegate. Create a delegate property on view controller B and set your container view controller (view controller A) to be view controller B's delegate. When the button is pressed, send a message to the delegate (`[self.delegate buttonPressed]`), which B will then receive. Now B can add another child view controller (D), which it can present in any way you'd like.

Using parentViewController may work, but this property may be nil if you ever decide to use that view controller on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Controller B should go ahead and call `-presentViewController:animated:completion:` on `self`. This method will present a view controller modally from the first one in the hierarchy that returns `YES` from `-definesPresentationContext`, starting with the controller that received the message. If you want the controller's view to be fullscreen with respect to controller A, override that method and return `YES`.

From the [`UIViewController` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/definesPresentationContext):

> `@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL definesPresentationContext`
>
> When a view controller is presented, iOS starts with the presenting
>   view controller and asks it if it wants to provide the presentation
>   context. If the presenting view controller does not provide a context,
>   then iOS asks the presenting view controller’s parent view controller.
>   iOS searches up through the view controller hierarchy until a view
>   controller provides a presentation context. If no view controller
>   offers to provide a context, the window’s root view controller
>   provides the presentation context.
>
> If a view controller returns YES, then it provides a presentation
>   context. The portion of the window covered by the view controller’s
>   view determines the size of the presented view controller’s view. The
>   default value for this property is NO.